# CounDownTimer how to set it for counting 2 times?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm doing an app which will use `CountDownTimer`
I would like to use 1 countdowntimer for 2 count downs.
If the time finishes, then a new time starts immediately, and so on.

For now I have something like this:

```
cdt = new CounDownTimer(time,1000) {
    public void onTick(…) {
        //code
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        //and here I'm thinking to add a new time, but it doesn't work
    }
};
```

How to do that? Or maybe is there other easier option to solve that problem?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your class newMyCountdownTimer(time, interval).start();

```
private class MyCountdownTimer extends CountDownTimer
{


    public MyCountdownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        if (somecondition is satisfied) // be carefull otherwise the countdown keeps running
        { 
        // newTime and newInterval are variables in the outer class  
            new MyCountdownTimer(newTime, newInterval).start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: and what if I want to change the time (for example 10000, not 5000)? how to do that?